# Clear content of cell A2 if A2 value same with A1

Tags: vba, excel

I have lists of different value in column A and B which contents same value for several rows respectively. like the following:

```
        BEFORE
  column A |   column B
1.   a             b
2.   a             b 
3.   a             b 
4.   a             b  
5.   z             z
6.   z             z
7.   z             z
8.   z             z

         AFTER
  column A |   column B
1.   a             b
2.                 
3.                 
4.                  
5.   z             z
6.                
7.                
8.
```

How do I delete the duplicate cell with former rows cell in same column? Like the After.

I have done the following so far:

```
Sub clear()
Dim x
Dim c

x = 1
c = Range("a1").Value

Do Until Cells(x, 1) = ""
    If Cells(x, 1) = Cells(x + 1, 1) Then
        Cells(x + 1, 1) = Range().ClearContents  
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub clear()
Dim cRow As Long
Dim CellValue As String

cRow = 2 ' start the loop in row 2
CellValue = Range("a1").Value

Do Until Cells(cRow, 1) = ""
    If Cells(cRow, 1) = CellValue Then
        Cells(cRow, 1).ClearContents
        Cells(cRow, 2).ClearContents ' clear column B cell
    Else
        CellValue = Cells(cRow, 1) ' when the cell value changes,
    End If
    cRow = cRow + 1 ' increment the row number so the next loop goes to the next row
Loop
End Sub
```

I prefer variables with descriptive names over `x` and `c`.

Some issues with your code were:

- Range must have a parameter, but you don't need Range when you already have the cell object with Cells()
- you did not increment the variable that sets the row
- the cleared cell became the new current cell and since it had just been cleared, the loop would end
- you never used the `c` variable, but it is useful to keep a record of the comparison string.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to consider the following "array" approach should speed be an issue:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim myArr As Variant, refVal As Variant

    With Worksheets("MySheet") '<--| change "MySheet" with your actual sheet name
        With Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("A:B")) '<--| consider only columns A and B rows down to the worksheet used range last one
            myArr = .Value ''<--|  store values in array
            For j = LBound(myArr, 2) To UBound(myArr, 2) '<--| loop through array columns
                refVal = myArr(1, j) '<--| get column fiurst reference value
                For i = LBound(myArr, 1) + 1 To UBound(myArr, 1) '<--| loop through form current column 2nd row downwards
                    If myArr(i, j) = refVal Then '<--| if there's a duplicate...
                        myArr(i, j) = "" '<--| ...erase it
                    Else '<--| otherwise...
                        refVal = myArr(i, j) '<--| ... get the new non duplicate value as the reference one
                    End If
                Next i
            Next j
            .Value = myArr '<--| write back array to worksheet
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

using `Option Explicit` statement is a safe habit that at the cost of some little extra work to declare all variables pays you back with much more control over your code and much less issues in debugging and maintaining it

using full range reference (like `Worksheets("MySheet").Range(...)`) is a good habit to avoid issues due to user sheet jumping selections

Answer (score 0):

To complement the answers from teylyn and user3598756, you could work from bottom to top to check the values:

```
Public Sub myClear(Optional ByRef wks As Worksheet = Nothing)
    Dim c As Range
    Dim col As Long
    If wks Is Nothing Then Set wks = ActiveSheet
    For col = 1 To 2   'Columns A and B
        Set c = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, col).Rows.End(xlUp)
        Do While c.Row > 1
            If c.Value = c.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then c.ClearContents
            Set c = c.Offset(-1, 0)
        Loop
    Next col
End Sub
```

The sub will work by default on the `ActiveSheet`, but you can give in parameter the actual sheet you want to work on.